# jQuery datepicker not work inside the Codeigniter and Bootsrap modal form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

I have a problem using **jQuery datepicker** inside the modal form. But worked when i'm not using it in the modal. Can anyone help me and give me some advice? Sorry for bad english. This is the code i have.

```
<div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <!-- MODAL STICK UP  -->
    <div class="modal fade stick-up" id="reg_pasien" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reg_pasien" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header clearfix ">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="pg-close fs-14"></i>
            </button>
            <h4 class="p-b-5"><span class="semi-bold">Registrasi</span> Pasien</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                    <label>nama lengkap</label>
                    <input id="namalengkap" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama lengkap pasien">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                    <label class="col-sm-9 control-label">Jenis Kelamin</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="radio radio-primary">
                      <input type="radio" value="L" name="optionyes" id="boy">
                        <label for="boy">Laki - laki</label>
                        <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="P" name="optionyes" id="girl">
                        <label for="girl">Perempuan</label>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                    <label>Alamat</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="alamatpasien" placeholder="contoh: Jl. Margorejo Indah 115A"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                    <label>Kota</label>
                    <input id="kotapasien" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. Surabaya">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                    <label>Propinsi</label>
                    <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
                      <option value="-"> -- Pilih Propinsi -- </option>
                      <option value="Aceh">Aceh</option>
                      <option value="Bali">Bali</option>
                      <option value="Banten">Banten</option>
                      <option value="Bengkulu">Bengkulu</option>
                      <option value="Gorontalo">Gorontalo</option>
                      <option value="Jakarta">Jakarta</option>
                      <option value="Jambi">Jambi</option>
                      <option value="Jawa Barat">Jawa Barat</option>
                      <option value="Jawa Tengah">Jawa Tengah</option>
                      <option value="Jawa Timur">Jawa Timur</option>
                      <option value="Kalimantan Barat">Kalimantan Barat</option>
                      <option value="Kalimantan Selatan">Kalimantan Selatan</option>
                      <option value="Kalimantan Tengah">Kalimantan Tengah</option>
                      <option value="Kalimantan Utara">Kalimantan Utara</option>
                      <option value="Kepulauan Bangka Belitung">Kepulauan Bangka Belitung</option>
                      <option value="Kepulauan Riau">Kepulauan Riau</option>
                      <option value="Lampung">Lampung</option>
                      <option value="Maluku">Maluku</option>
                      <option value="Maluku Utara">Maluku Utara</option>
                      <option value="Nusa Tenggara Barat">Nusa Tenggara Barat</option>
                      <option value="Nusa Tenggara Timur">Nusa Tenggara Timur</option>
                      <option value="Papua">Papua</option>
                      <option value="Papua Barat">Papua Barat</option>
                      <option value="Riau">Riau</option>
                      <option value="Sulawesi Barat">Sulawesi Barat</option>
                      <option value="Sulawesi Selatan">Sulawesi Selatan</option>
                      <option value="Sulawesi Tengah">Sulawesi Tengah</option>
                      <option value="Sulawesi Utara">Sulawesi Utara</option>
                      <option value="Sumatera Barat">Sumatera Barat</option>
                      <option value="Sumatera Selatan">Sumatera Selatan</option>
                      <option value="Sumatera Utara">Sumatera Utara</option>
                      <option value="Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta">Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                    <label>Tempat Lahir</label>
                    <input id="lahirpasien" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. Surabaya">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group col-sm-6">
                  <label>Tanggal Lahir</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pilih Tanggal" id="datepicker-component2">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="add-app" type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-cons">Registrasi</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-cons" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the code for **datepicker** inside *formelements.js* that i used to store the jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Multiselect - Select2 plug-in
    $("#multi").val(["Jim", "Lucy"]).select2();
    //Date Pickers
    $('#datepicker-range, #datepicker-component, #datepicker-component2').datepicker();
    $('#datepicker-embeded').datepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1"

    });

    $('#datepicker-custom').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: '+5d',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
   });


    var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
    $confModal.on('hidden', function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
    });

    $confModal.modal({ backdrop : false });
```

Thats all i can inform to you, hope you can help me.

Comment: You need to add a <form>. You can't just willy nilly throw <input> wherever and expect things to work. Proper HTML first, then we can discuss helping.

Comment: oh sorry for my code, the code is inside <form> exactly. My problem is just "It works normally outside the modals, but not works inside the modals"

Comment: update your code in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i'm googling for the answer. Now, i know where is the problem come from. It was not jQuery problem, it's just on css problem. I add inline css class:

```
<style>
  .datepicker{z-index:+1, !important}
</style>
```

So, it's just like layering problem inside the modals.